# Is there an easy way of achieving a multirow&multicolumn views carousel?

Tags: views, javascript

In my website I'm trying to do something like the carousel set under the portrait image in this web: http://www.maersk.com/en (I'm not affiliated to Maersk in any way). I don't want to do the animation done with the mouseover in the tiles.

What I have seen here is that this is done in some way that there is a flexslider with some gridlayouts that are cycling with the links attached.

I would want to do something similar to show my recent articles/pages posted in my web, being nodes of different type(some could be image, and others, text, so I thougt of creating a field in all my node types being a richtextfield, and show that on the View -I don't know if this is possible, but if it fails, I will use an image and whatever-).

I'm not asking anybody to do this for me. What I would ask is some advice about modules that could help me to achieve this in a more or less easy way, or any quick hints that could pass per your head.

Would be very, very appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: **Quick hint:** use the theme template force.